# How to get smtp from mx records?

Tags: email, outlook, smtp, gmail, imap

I am trying to get the SMTP of an email from the MX records. For instance, `nslookup` if I type in `outlook.com` what I get is `outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com` but actually the SMTP is `smtp-mail.outlook.com`. How can I get this record `smtp-mail.outlook.com` from the MX records rather than google for each domain what their SMTP is?

Even for `163.com` the mx record I get is `163mx03.mxmail.netease.com` now I have to google what is the smtp for `netease.com` and I figured out from internet that it is `smtp.ym.163.com`.

Is there a simpler or a standardised procedure to get this output? I even tried sending a mail from that email and in email header also there is no SMTP provided like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any mail delivery from a@domain1.com to b@domain2.com, there are generally* two SMTP servers used.  The first is a@domain1.com’s *submission* server, used for a to submit mail to other people.  The second is domain2.com’s *destination*** server, used to receive messages for domain2.com’s users.  So an email goes from a’s email client to a’s submission server.  The submission server relays it to domain2.com’s destination server, where b can then retrieve it.

The MX record represents the destination SMTP server, that other providers should use to send mail for that server’s users.  For example, the `MX` for outlook.com is the SMTP server your server would use to relay messages to email addresses `xyz@outlook.com`.  It is *not* the server outlook.com’s submission users use to send mail to other people.

Submission servers can theoretically be stored in DNS `SRV` records, but this isn’t widely deployed. Mail Clients usually guess using heuristics (try smtp and mail.domain2.com) or using databases that have been collected (eg, thunderbirds `ispdb`), or configured by the end user.

For example, `thunderbird` documents their [autoconfiguration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration) methods.  It is a combination of a database, a special web server at autconfig.domain.com, admin provided configuration file, and guessing.

*: in more complicated setups, even more can be used (like internal submission and edge servers), but this is the baseline.
**: this is more precisely called a relay server, I use destination as a more precise name for the final relay server.

Comment: so basically there is no way that I can get the submission server name?

Comment: @Derik002 There is no standardized way.  I am not sure of their terms of use, but you may be able use Tbird's ISPDB. For example: https://autoconfig.thunderbird.net/v1.1/outlook.com

Comment: you are a lifesaver. almost all domains SMTP is listed there

Comment: @Derik002 If this answer helps you, please consider upvoting and accepting it.